# How to change user without closing applications running?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, login, user-accounts

The problem I have is that multiple users need to RDP to a machine to check the status of an application that is running. Normally, when users login/logout, the applications will stop and the user will have his own environment. What I need, is that the users can login/logout, while the application will continue running and the newly logged-in user will be able to check the status of it. Something like a shared desktop for different users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like Transparent Screen Lock https://www.e-motional.com/TScreenLock.html . It allows for authentication and unlocking an existing profile with multiple user credentials.

Comment: That's a good approach. I am looking for anything a little less intrusive, or more native.